# Gradle How to show custom build time warning for usage of certain C++ APIs

Tags: c++, gradle, build

I am currently using Gradle to build a C++ project. It has a gradle plugin which resolves all the project dependencies and do the actual build by running `make`. I am wondering if there's a way to show some custom compile time warnings. Say for example, some people called an api in a library

```
void warning_api(){}
```

I want to show a warning message when he/she compiled the code like:

```
[Warning] The usage of warning_api() is not recommended.
```

I am new to gradle and wondering if there's a way to do this either in the gradle plugin or gradle itself? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use `deprecated` C++14 attribute:

```
[[deprecated("The usage of warning_api() is not recommended.")]]  void warning_api(){}
```

Comment: Thanks! The api is not deprecated. Besides, it's a third party api so I don't want to create a local mirror just to show the warning message.

Comment: @Rockingchief There is no need to modify third-party code, attribute can be added separately.

Comment: Can you clarify how to add attribute without modifying the third-party library? It's not me calling this api but I want to warn other application developers who tries to call this API.

Comment: @Rockingchief Exactly the same way as it is written in the answer, except there is no need for `{}`

Comment: So I guess the real question I have is where should I put this line of code? I can't put them in the application code because application developer is writing the code. I can't put them in the third party library without creating a local branch. The only thing I have control over is the build script we have.